# Background-size: cover suddenly stopped working in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, css, cover

Is anyone else having this issue?  I create websites for a living, and some employ the use of the css property `background-size: cover`.  All of the sudden about 1 week ago, all of the sites with this property no longer display right in Google Chrome. (all other browsers are working fine.)  Is anyone else experiencing this?  Is it just MY google chrome or did something change?  Because the backgrounds were displaying properly until about a week ago, and I did not *change* anything. They just stopped displaying properly, seemingly out of nowhere....

Comment: lmfao this site is retarded.... I cant answer my own question for SEVEN HOURS!!!!! even though I figured it out. I only wanted to answer in case someone else has this problem.  The issue was I had to FIRST define my background image. THEN set the size property.  Setting the size first and defining the image second will not work.  This however did NOT matter about a week ago, its still worked despite what order they were in.

Comment: In fact, it was still working fine in Safari when it stopped working in Chrome.  Which means some browsers don't care about the order in which the css is parsed.

Comment: @user1576497 Thanks for your efforts. Please post the answer when possible, and accept it when possible (48 hours after asking question).

Comment: Best practice: always set `background-image` first and then `background-size`.

Comment: @Ana I don't see how it's a best practice, sounds like a bug in Chrome.

Comment: @LeeWhitney http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/02/CSS-Background-shorthand-coming-to-mobile-WebKit-browsers

Comment: @Ana, wow you are absolutely correct thanks for the citation.  You should get credit for submitting this as an answer because it really explains the root of the issue. +1.

Comment: user1576497 - this site is amazing.  Search for a coding problem on google and, over time, 75% of your answers will originate here.  Plus it gives you real-time support from a vast community of users to answer any problems you have that you can't find by searching... Rather than complaining about the fact that Chrome updated their background shorthand, why not take some time to explain it to users like myself who are searching for the "why" to this problem?  @Ana +1, thanks :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Best practice: always set background-image first and then background-size.

Comment: +1. I just got bitten in the rear by this. Putting it in the wrong order reverted in Chrome to auto and the inspector was not offering any clues as to why.

Comment: @maify +100 awesome answer

Answer (score 17):

You only need to use !important :

```
background-size: cover !important;
```

Comment: +1, Weird but true. This also applies to any other `background-*` attributes which aren't behaving correctly, in my case `background-repeat` and `background-position`.

Comment: This works for me! I used the background properties with !important, and I guess that background-size should has it too.

Comment: Weird. Had the exact same problem, but this fixed it.

Answer (score 14):

I just ran into this problem in Chrome, too.

None of the above answers worked for me. Specifically, I was trying to set the `<body>` element background to `background-size: cover`. However, the  background image would never extend vertically to fill the page.

After some trial and error, I found that setting the `<html>` element width and height to 100% fixed the problem in Chrome. (For what it's worth, changing the `<body>` element's width and height seemed to have no effect.)

In my css, I have the following rules to fix the issue:

```
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem all of a sudden w/ not only GC but also FF and Opera. i was using a php function to pull random images for my background and this is what i had....

CSS:

```
.main-slideshow .video img  {   
  cursor:pointer;
  width:550px !important;       
  height:340px !important;   
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  -moz-background-size:cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover; 
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;   }
```

and HTML/PHP:

```
$result .='<img alt="" style="background:url('.$thumbnail.')" src="/images/play1.png" /> ';
```

it was working for some days and suddenly `background-repeat` and `background-size` stopped working. so this morning i found out that the following changes are working perfectly for GC (v21), FF (v14), Opera (v12) and Safari (v5.1.7)...still no luck w/ IE though :(

CSS:

```
.main-slideshow .video img  {   
  cursor:pointer;
  width:550px !important;       
  height:340px !important;   
  -moz-background-size:cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover; 
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;   }
```

HTML/PHP:

```
    $result .='<img alt="" style="background-image:url('.$thumbnail.')" style="background-repeat: no-repeat" style="background-size:cover" src="/images/play1.png" />';
```

may be it's a lousy solution but it's working for me (so far) hope this helps some one :)

Comment: You should combine both `style` attribute statements into one for valid HTML, so the `background-image: url(...);` should go in front of the `background-repeat`. Now you're declaring the `style` twice, which might cause problems in the browser. At least it is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

**The following is a solution to the problem, but it won't be for everybody. I estimate that this solution will help a minority of the people experiencing the author's problem.**

The background-size option can stop working in chrome if your container is too small, vertically, compared to your background image.

I was in a situation where I had to position a small portion of a large background image across a div that was 7 pixels tall.

In the Chrome debugger, changing the div height to 9 pixels "snapped" the background-size into place.

My ultimate solution was to restructure my divs so that I would not run into this problem.

To see if this solution will help you, in the Chrome debugger, enlarge your div. If, at some point, the background-size snaps into place, then you know this is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but has similiar issue and it turned out I needed to add and `&nbsp;` to the empty div's I was applying `background-size: cover` to.

Answer (score 0):

You must do CSS hacks for google chrome.

```
Use body:nth-of-type(1) .elementOrClassName{property:value;}
```

only for google chrome.

for your case,

```
nth-of-type(1) .elementOrClassName{background-size:80px 60px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
background-size:contain;

Answer (score 0):

For me, following worked for Chrome, IE 8, IE 9:

```
.itemFullBg{
background:url('image/path/name.png') no-repeat;

-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-size:100% 100%;      
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader
    (src='image/path/name.png',sizingMethod='scale');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the problem by setting the height of the tag.
For example, if you have a page that has a background image, set the height of the html and body tags in the CSS, like so:

```
html { height:100%;  min-height:100%;  } body{  min-height:100%;  }
```

hope this helps

Answer (score -3):

Instead of using:

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Use:

```
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
-o-background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: this will cause stretching/squishing of the image if it's not the exact dimensions of the element you're trying to "cover" (the whole point of the cover property in the first place)