# Fullscreen image with border that shrinks depending by device resolution

Tags: javascript, css, fullscreen

Hello everybody I want to make a homepage with a fullscreen image on the background with a border all around.

I have been able to do it as you can see from this jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/dforce/3j5uo5qo/1/

but I would like that the border shrinks when the resolution is smaller or desappear on resolution is smaller than 979px.

I use this script to make the border:

```
    <script>
$theBorder=35; //border around image (change top and left values of #bg accordingly)
$bg=$("#bg");

$bgimg=$("#bg #bgimg");

$preloader=$("#preloader");
//]]> 

$(window).load(function() {
    FullScreenBackground($bgimg,$bg);

    $(window).resize(function() {
        FullScreenBackground($bgimg,$bg);
    });
});

$bgimg.load(function() {
    var $this=$(this);
    FullScreenBackground($this,$bg);
    $preloader.fadeOut("fast");
    $this.delay(200).fadeIn("slow");
});

function FullScreenBackground(theItem,theContainer){
    var winWidth=$(window).width();
    var winHeight=$(window).height();
    var imageWidth=$(theItem).width();
    var imageHeight=$(theItem).height();
    var picHeight = imageHeight / imageWidth;
    var picWidth = imageWidth / imageHeight;
    if ((winHeight / winWidth) < picHeight) {
        $(theItem).css("width",winWidth);
        $(theItem).css("height",picHeight*winWidth);
    } else {
        $(theItem).css("height",winHeight);
        $(theItem).css("width",picWidth*winHeight);
    };
    $(theContainer).css("width",winWidth-($theBorder*2));
    $(theContainer).css("height",winHeight-($theBorder*2));
    $(theItem).css("margin-left",(winWidth- $(theItem).width())/2);
    $(theItem).css("margin-top",(winHeight- $(theItem).height())/2);
}
</script>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: what do you mean by _resolution smaller than 979px_ - width or height or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about responsive css?

Something like

```
<div id="mainimage">
    <div class="img"></div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background:#fff;
}

#mainimage {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
}

@media(max-width: 1300px) {
  #mainimage{
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
@media(max-width: 979px) {
  #mainimage{
    padding: 0px;
  }
}
.img{
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(http://www.piedicosta.com/jnuovo/images/big.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
  background-size: cover;
}
```

You can add transitions to make the change smoother, something like

```
#mainimage {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Hello Guig and thank you for your kind help!
It works like I want but I need this on a background image and not directly on an image...
Because I need to add some content (Like menu, etc...) on the image....

Do you think it is possible?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I edited the response. I usually prefers using `<img> and z-index for background things because I've found the background properties to be confusing (here you have to add the background property before the background size one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811203/background-size-cover-suddenly-stopped-working-in-google-chrome) else cover doesn't work...)

Comment: Hello Guig, thank you for your kind reply!
I need to add the image as a background for 2 reasons:
- I manage the background as a module on Joomla.
- I can replace the background with another module that manage an image slider

Anyway it seems it is working...

Thanks a lot for your kind help that has been crucial!

Comment: Glad it helped! If you find my (or anyone else) post as a good response to your problem, it would be nice to accept it the correct answer and give it some upvote so that future readers can easily know where to look

Answer (score 1):

hope this will help to you.try this

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Welcome !</title>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <style type="text/css">
      body{
        margin:0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    
      .maindiv{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color:black;
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-dwPiL6_mLUo/UzPrdohyk0I/AAAAAAAADds/LNvY6Hyp4Tc/s1600/Programmer+HD+Wallpaper+by+PCbots.png);
        background-position: center;
        display: none;
    
    
      }
    
    </style>
    
    
     <body>
    
    <div class="maindiv"></div> 
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".maindiv").fadeIn(4000)
      });
    
    </script>
    
     </body>
    </html>
```

**Note** if you want to put a responsive image without using bootstrap,
set it as  `div` `background-image` with `width` and `height` in `%` value.or

give your `div`

```
width:anyvalue%;
height:anyvalue%;
```

then put your `image` inside this `div` and for your image,set

```
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
```